# Is it possible to initialise a reference type through an initialisation list?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, initialization-list

Firstly, my apologies if this is a poor question.  I am new to C++.

I have a set of class headers that contain a reference type field, which is an interface (class built up from pure virtual functions).  I would like to initialise my class so that by default the reference type field is set to a certain "concrete" derived class, and this is done using the default constructor (parameterless!).  I would also like to be able to override this initialisation with another "concrete" derived class.

So far, I have class headers as follows:

```
class Foo {

public:

Foo();

Foo(IBar & bar);

protected:

/* Update 1: const field */
const IBar & bar;

...
}
```

But I am struggling with the implementation:

```
/* Is it possible to create the reference type through the initialisation list? */

/* Update 2: corrected initialisation of bar field from "BarDerivedA() bar" to "BarDerivedA()" */
Foo::Foo()
: bar(BarDerivedA())
{

}

/* Override */
Foo::Foo(IBar & bar)
: bar(bar)
{

}
```

**Update**
We found that using this potential design wasn't going to be efficient.  The default for `const IBar & bar` will almost always be the same object for every class with the field, with the exception of unit testing - we want to be able to swap in mock classes as required.

I don't want to constantly create the same object on the stack so will work on a factory for these group of objects.

I have gone down the route of a single constructor as follows:

```
Foo::Foo(IBar & bar)
: bar(bar)
{

}
```

If someone wants to provide an appropriate answer regarding the setting of class reference fields to a temporary object in the initialisation list (i.e. can only do it for const fields, and will go out of scope outside of the constructor) I will mark it as the accepted answer.  Or alternatively mark it as an appropriate duplicate.

Comment: Why not use a __pointer__?

Comment: Non-const lvalue references cannot bind to temporaries, so no, you have to have an instance of that concrete implementation to use in that case.

Comment: Not only possible, but required.

Comment: @PawełStawarz - I am avoiding pointers as I want these classes to be used on the stack.  Also, the field must always point to an instance of an object (null not valid).

Comment: As @chris said `Foo::Foo()
: bar(BarDerivedA bar())
{

}` is not possible

Comment: @chris - I updated the original question, the field is a constant if that makes any difference to my problem

Comment: @rasteve It still gives you warning as you are binding reference to a temporary value. But you should be fine as the life of the temporary gets extended till the const ref stays in scope.

Comment: Just realized that you are visual studio and VC has an extension where you can bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Comment: First, pointers do not mean 'heap',  Second, if you want a persistant reference to data, you need to manage the data lifetime separately.

Comment: @Jagannath - So essentially, the warning "C4413 - reference member is initialized to a temporary that doesn't persist after the constructor exits" can be ignored because I am using a const lvalue (which guarantees the lifetime of the temporary as the lifetime of the instance of Foo)?

Comment: mmm... seems to only hold true within the "lifetime of the constructor", as the warning states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add the default object in the class, something like:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : bar(defaultBar);{}
    Foo(IBar& bar) : bar(bar) {}

protected:
    const BarDerivedA defaultBar; // Before the reference.
    const IBar& bar;
};
```

Comment: This does everything that I originally asked but has the side effect of having a `BarDerivedA` created for every instance of the class, whether it is used or not.

Comment: @rasteve: You may make `defaultBar` static to share that instance between  every `Foo` instances.